# Cognito Error I/flutter ( 4963): Invalid argument(s): PASSWORD parameter is required

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, flutter, amazon-cognito

I am trying follow the Flutter pub.dev documentation for Cognito and AWS User Authentication. I am building a Flutter mobile app, and was able to successfully register users into my AWS user pool. I am trying to code the login functionality however it will not register any of the parameters that I am trying to give it. i.e password and username (email)

I have tried restarting the computer, Android Studios, tried following all AWS documentation, and re-writing the code on https://pub.dev/packages/amazon_cognito_identity_dart

AttributeArg ar1 = AttributeArg(name: 'USERNAME', value: userEmail);
    AttributeArg ar2 = AttributeArg(name: 'PASSWORD', value: userPassword);

```
final List<AttributeArg> authParams = [
  ar1,
  ar2,
];

AuthenticationDetails authDetails2 = AuthenticationDetails();

authDetails2.authParameters = authParams;

//final authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(
//authParameters: authDetails2.getAuthParameters());

final authDetails =
    new AuthenticationDetails(authParameters: authDetails2.authParameters);

setCognitoUser();
CognitoUserSession session;

cognitoUser.setAuthenticationFlowType('USER_PASSWORD_AUTH');

try {
  //session = await cognitoUser.initiateAuth(authDetails);
  session = await cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authDetails);
  // username: userEmail, password: userPassword));
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
print(session.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
```

I/flutter ( 4963): Invalid argument(s): PASSWORD parameter is required
E/flutter ( 4963): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'getAccessToken' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 4963): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 4963): Tried calling: getAccessToken()
E/flutter ( 4963): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:50:5)
E/flutter ( 4963): #1      Globals.logInUser (package:neurominer_app/globals.dart:76:19)
E/flutter ( 4963): 
E/flutter ( 4963): #2      _LoginScreenState.build. (package:neurominer_app/screens/login_screen.dart:155:34)
E/flutter ( 4963): #3      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:635:14)
E/flutter ( 4963): #4      _InkResponseState.build. (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:711:32)
E/flutter ( 4963): #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter ( 4963): #6      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:365:11)
E/flutter ( 4963): #7      TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:275:7)
E/flutter ( 4963): #8      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:455:9)
E/flutter ( 4963): #9      PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:75:13)
E/flutter ( 4963): #10     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:102:11)
E/flutter ( 4963): #11     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218:19)
E/flutter ( 4963): #12     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
E/flutter ( 4963): #13     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter ( 4963): #14     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter ( 4963): #15     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
E/flutter ( 4963): #16     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1136:13)
E/flutter ( 4963): #17     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
E/flutter ( 4963): #18     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:931:7)
E/flutter ( 4963): #19     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:250:10)
E/flutter ( 4963): #20     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:159:5)
E/flutter ( 4963):

Comment: Looking at the docs it looks like your `authDetails` variable needs to be like this: final authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(
    username: 'email@inspire.my', password: 'Password001'); So I'm assuming "ar2" in that array at the top is probably coming in null or invalid.

Comment: I changed some code around and re-ran everything. I believe the issue turned out to be that from a separate screen (my login screen) I was not sending non-null values over. Therefore it was coming up username/password null.

Answer (score 0):

Correct code from https://pub.dev/packages/amazon_cognito_identity_dart

Just needed to make sure that since I was splitting up my code between multiple screens (importing classes and calling methods to do user authentication) that valid username and password (non-null) values were being used to authenticate.

```
final userPool = new CognitoUserPool(
    'ap-southeast-1_xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
final cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(
    'email@inspire.my', userPool);
final authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(
    username: 'email@inspire.my', password: 'Password001');
CognitoUserSession session;
try {
  session = await cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authDetails);
} catch(e){
  print(e);
}
```